# How to read data Asynchronously in C# from python script

Tags: python, c#, opencv

I am trying to read python script output continuously (In python I am tracking a colored ball and printing it's x, y and radius) from WPF C#.

1. I tried socket communication

```
            using (var requester = new ZSocket(ZSocketType.REQ))
            {
                // Connect
                requester.Connect("tcp://127.0.0.1:5555");

                for (; ; )
                {
                    string requestText = "Hello";
                    Console.Write("Sending {0}...", requestText);

                    // Send
                    requester.Send(new ZFrame(requestText));

                    // Receive
                    using (ZFrame reply = requester.ReceiveFrame())
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(" Received: {0} {1}!", requestText, reply.ReadString());
                    }
                }
            }
```

2. I tried calling python from C# Process

```
            private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            string python = @"C:\Desktop\test\venv\Scripts\python.exe";
            // python app to call 

            string myPythonApp = @"C:\Users\Desktop\test\main.py";

            // Create new process start info 
            ProcessStartInfo myProcessStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(python);

            // make sure we can read the output from stdout 
            myProcessStartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            myProcessStartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;

            myProcessStartInfo.Arguments = myPythonApp;

            Process myProcess = new Process();
            // assign start information to the process 
            myProcess.StartInfo = myProcessStartInfo;

            // start the process 
            myProcess.OutputDataReceived += MyProcess_OutputDataReceived;
            myProcess.Start();
            myProcess.BeginOutputReadLine();

            // Read the standard output of the app we called.  
            // in order to avoid deadlock we will read output first 
            // and then wait for process terminate: 
            //StreamReader myStreamReader = myProcess.StandardOutput;
            //string myString = myStreamReader.ReadLine();

            //await myStreamReader.ReadAsync(result, 0, (int)myStreamReader.BaseStream.Length);
           
            // wait exit signal from the app we called and then close it. 
            //myProcess.WaitForExit();
            //myProcess.Close();

            // write the output we got from python app 
            //Console.WriteLine("Value received from script: " + myString);
        }

        private void MyProcess_OutputDataReceived(object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs e)
        {
            
            Console.WriteLine("++++");
        }
```

3. Python writes data to txt file, C# reads from that file

```
            Console.WriteLine("hi");
            for (; ; )
            {
                if (File.Exists(textFile))
                {
                    using (StreamReader file = new StreamReader(textFile))
                    {
                        int counter = 0;
                        string ln;

                        while ((ln = file.ReadLine()) != null)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine(ln);
                            counter++;
                        }
                        file.Close();

                    }
                }
```

All the cases python is holding the thread and not allowing c# to access it. Now I am working 2 method i.e. getting data from Process, but MyProcess_OutputDataReceived is not triggering.

```
import sys
from collections import deque
from PIL import Image, ImageOps, ImageDraw

import numpy as np
import argparse
import imutils
import cv2
import time
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
#import zmq

#context = zmq.Context()
#socket = context.socket(zmq.REP)
#socket.bind("tcp://*:5555")

#object tracking def start
ap = argparse.ArgumentParser()
ap.add_argument("-v", "--video",
                help="path to the (optional) video file")
ap.add_argument("-b", "--buffer", type=int, default=64,
                help="max buffer size")
args = vars(ap.parse_args())

greenLower = (29, 86, 6)
greenUpper = (64, 255, 255)
pts = deque(maxlen=args["buffer"])

if not args.get("video", False):
    camera = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
else:
    camera = cv2.VideoCapture(args["video"])

Data_Features = ['x', 'y', 'time']
Data_Points = pd.DataFrame(data=None, columns=Data_Features, dtype=float)

start = time.time()
#object tracking def end

#file1 = open("myfile.txt","w")
#L = ["This is Delhi \n","This is Paris \n","This is London \n"]
#file1.write("Hello \n")
#file1.writelines(L)
#file1.close()

while True:
    #  Wait for next request from client
    #message = socket.recv()
    #print("Received request: %s" % message)
    #  Do some 'work'
    #time.sleep(1)
    #  Send reply back to client
    #socket.send("World")

    #object track vids start

    (grabbed, frame) = camera.read()
    current_time = time.time() - start
    if args.get("video") and not grabbed:
        break
    frame = imutils.resize(frame, width=1600)

    # frame2 = imutils.resize
    #blurred = cv2.GaussianBlur(frame, (11, 11), 0)
    hsv = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
    mask = cv2.inRange(hsv, greenLower, greenUpper)
    mask = cv2.erode(mask, None, iterations=2)
    mask = cv2.dilate(mask, None, iterations=2)
    cnts = cv2.findContours(mask.copy(), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL,
                            cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)[-2]
    center = None


    if len(cnts) > 0:

        # find the largest contour in the mask, then use
        # it to compute the minimum enclosing circle and
        # centroid
        c = max(cnts, key=cv2.contourArea)
        ((x, y), radius) = cv2.minEnclosingCircle(c)
        M = cv2.moments(c)
        center = (int(M["m10"] / M["m00"]), int(M["m01"] / M["m00"]))

        # only proceed if the radius meets a minimum size
        if (radius < 300) & (radius > 10):
            # draw the circle and centroid on the frame,
            # then update the list of tracked points
            cv2.circle(frame, (int(x), int(y)), int(radius),
                       (0, 255, 255), 2)


            sys.stdout.write(str(x) + '\n')

            #print(str(x))
            #file1 = open("myfile.txt", "w")
            #file1.write(str(x))
            #file1.close()
            #time.sleep(1)
            cv2.circle(frame, center, 5, (0, 0, 255), -1)

            # Save The Data Points
            Data_Points.loc[Data_Points.size / 3] = [x, y, current_time]
            

    pts.appendleft(center)
    for i in range(1, len(pts)):
        # if either of the tracked points are None, ignore
        # them
        if pts[i - 1] is None or pts[i] is None:
            continue

        # otherwise, compute the thickness of the line and
        # draw the connecting lines
        thickness = int(np.sqrt(args["buffer"] / float(i + 1)) * 2.5)
        cv2.line(frame, pts[i - 1], pts[i], (0, 0, 255), thickness)
    cv2.imshow("Frame", frame)

    key = cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF
    if key == ord("q"):
        break
    #object tracking vids end

h = 0.2
X0 = -3
Y0 = 20
time0 = 0
theta0 = 0.3

# Applying the correction terms to obtain actual experimental data
Data_Points['x'] = Data_Points['x'] - X0
Data_Points['y'] = Data_Points['y'] - Y0
Data_Points['time'] = Data_Points['time'] - time0

# Calulataion of theta value
Data_Points['theta'] = 2 * np.arctan(
    Data_Points['y'] * 0.0000762 / h)  # the factor correspons to pixel length in real life
Data_Points['theta'] = Data_Points['theta'] - theta0

# Creating the 'Theta' vs 'Time' plot
plt.plot(Data_Points['theta'], Data_Points['time'])
plt.xlabel('Theta')
plt.ylabel('Time')

# Export The Data Points As cvs File and plot
Data_Points.to_csv('Data_Set.csv', sep=",")
plt.savefig('Time_vs_Theta_Graph.svg', transparent=True)

# cleanup the camera and close any open windows
camera.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Please help me.
Thank you in advance.

Ranjith

Comment: It's not a good idea to use a file, but accessing a locked file is easy. You need to open the file in ReadOnly mode.

Comment: Thank you very much, I know that is not a correct way. But it will serve my purpose. Later if I get better solution I will change that part. It's working now. :)